# .NET Core 3.1 Worker Service / no application insight request/dependency events

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-application-insights

I have a .NET Core 3.1 Worker Service project.

I setup application insights as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service#net-core-30-worker-service-application

I can confirm I receive trace and event as expected. They are visible in AI portal.

However I cannot get any dependency or request events.
I know my worker is not an ASP.NET web app however my worker makes external calls (Azure Relay, Azure Key vault, generic HTTP ones, etc.) so I would expect to get this kind of events ?

Is any manual additional setup required to enable those modules ?

Comment: Can you share how you are making http calls? Azure dependency calls based on http are automatically tracked.

Comment: I am using standard HttpClient class... For instance...

(...)
 var httpClient = new HttpClient();
 var internalResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
(...)